# How do you get relative mouse position inside a VisualElement with new Unity UI Toolkit?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I'm switching over to the new UI-Toolkit (which is css-based). Using the old "canvas" and component-based ui system, I would first see if the mouse was within a ui element with a script attached to that specific ui gameobject with two functions:

```
public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    mouseInScreen = true;
}
public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    mouseInScreen = false;
}
```

Then I would simply call *if(OnPointerEnter.mouseInScreen == true)* to find out if the mouse is in.

Unfortunately, the new UI uses one gameobject for the entire ui elements, so I'm not sure how to do this. Also, I would need to know the relative position within a UI VisualElement. (ex. mouse is 80px from left, 130px from top of t his specific element).

This new toolkit is amazing, but very new. So it is very hard to find information on it so far.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I found a solution to one of the issues I had (how to determine if mouse is over a specific element.)

I used *PointerDownEvent* since I also need to know when the user clicks in it, but *PointerEnterEvent* works great for my original question.

```
myUIelement.RegisterCallback<PointerDownEvent>(OnPointerDownEvent, TrickleDown.TrickleDown);
```

Then I do what I need in this method

```
private void OnPointerDownEvent(PointerDownEvent evt)
{ ... }
```

All I need to figure out is how to get the position of the "pointer" within that ui Element now. There is a property for *OnPointerDownEvent* called "**localPosition**", but I'm not sure how to use it exactly.

Comment: Found [this forum post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/get-mouse-position-relative-to-ui-element.697715/) which gets the relative position of the mouse within a rect using [RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, this uses RectTransforms. The new UI Toolkit doesn't use any standard unity ui components like RectTransform. It uses uss (like css).

Comment: My mistake. Looking at the reference for PointerEventBase<T0>, there is the property `localPosition` which is "The pointer position in the current target coordinate system." and the property `position` which is "The pointer position in the Screen or World coordinate system.".   So an element with a hook into PointerEnter/Leave/Down (as well as others) will have access to those through the event data.

Comment: @hijinxbassist I was able to read through the documentation of your recommendation and figure out a solution to one of the issues, but I'm not sure how to use the "localPosition" property. I've updated my post to show what I've got working so far. If you're able to help me out with my final issue, you should post it as an answer so I can give you credit at least. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my own answer after a little help in the comments and doing some research.

First get the element like so:

```
VisualElement rootUI = GetComponent<UIDocument>().rootVisualElement;
myUIelement = rootUI.Q<VisualElement>("ElementNameInUIBuilder");
```

Call this in start:

```
myUIelement.RegisterCallback<PointerDownEvent>(OnPointerDownEvent, TrickleDown.TrickleDown);
```

Then create a function:

```
private void OnPointerDownEvent(PointerDownEvent evt)
```

{ ... }

And in this function just use "*evt.localPosition*" to get the local coordinates within the ui element.